# What is the word or phrase that means "art" (as a general aesthetic quality of something)

Tags: meaning, word-choice

In reference to a video game, I might say:

> "*Braid* is a rewarding puzzle game with beautiful art."

In this sense, I don't mean art as in a specific piece of art in the game, I don't mean art as a skill or craft, and I certainly am not referring to "the" arts. However, those definitions are all I could find in dictionaries.

So, what can I use to refer to something's own general style or visuals?

Answer (score 3):

The first words that come to mind are 「美意識{びいしき}」 and 「美的{びてき}センス」.

To use those in sentences, one could say:

・「このゲーム（に）は（製作者{せいさくしゃ}の）高い美意識/美的センスが感じられる。」

・「このゲームの美的センスは優{すぐ}れている。」

etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use アート, and I think it's the most common choice in game contexts. If you really want to make it clear that you are not referring to a specific work, you can use アートスタイル. (美意識 primarily refers to someone's ability.)

> Braidは美しいアートを備えたやりがいのあるゲームです。